# Pause shell script until user presses enter

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

When I am reading a file

sample script

```
while read file
do
temp = $(echo $file)
read -p "Press Enter to continue"
echo $temp
done < test.txt
```

I want to pause the script until I press ENTER

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) reads from standard input by default, which is redirected to the file, so it's getting the line from the file. You can redirect back to the terminal:

```
read -p "Press Enter to continue" </dev/tty
```

Another option would be to use a different FD for the file redirection

```
while read -u 3
do
    ...
done 3< test.txt
```