# nested bash while loop not taking user input

Tags: bash, while-loop, nested

I'm trying to write in bash (Mac OSX but with GNU shell programs installed) a "Yes or No" interactive line by line iteration reading from an input file. As an example, suppose I have a file with numbers from 1 to 5 (one by line) as an input and I want to ask wether they are prime numbers.

```
#!bin/bash
while read NUMBER
  do echo "Prime number (answer y or n)?"
  while read ANSWER
  do
    test "$ANSWER" == "y" && echo "Prime" && break
    test "$ANSWER" == "n" && echo "Non-prime" && break
    test "$ANSWER" != "y" -a "$ANSWER" != "n" && echo "Type y or n"
  done
done < 1_to_5_file.txt
```

The below output doesn't open for user input

```
Prime number (answer y or n)?
Type y or n
Type y or n
Type y or n
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pause Shell script until Press Enter in while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075364/pause-shell-script-until-press-enter-in-while-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the outer while loop's stdin (the input to the script) is set to read from 1_to_5_file.txt, that is inherited to all commands running inside the while loop. One way to work around that is to save the original stdin in a different descriptor, which we can then use inside the loop. In my example I will store it in file descriptor 3.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read NUMBER
  do echo "Prime number (answer y or n)?"
  while read ANSWER
  do
    test "$ANSWER" == "y" && echo "Prime" && break
    test "$ANSWER" == "n" && echo "Non-prime" && break
    test "$ANSWER" != "y" -a "$ANSWER" != "n" && echo "Type y or n"
  done 0<&3
done 3<&0 < 1_to_5_file.txt
```

The last line makes a copy of file descriptor 0 in file descriptor 3. Then inside the loop file descriptor 3 points to the original stdin. On the inner while loop's last line I then copy file descriptor 3 to file descriptor 0 which thus makes the stdin inside the loop again point to the original stdin.

For the record, "<" is the same as "0<" and ">" is the same as "1>". Thus the `0<&3` could also have been written just `<&3`.

Another, more elagant solution proposed by @chepner would be to open the 1_to_5_file.txt on file descriptor 3 instead and just change the first read command to read from that one instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read NUMBER <&3
  do echo "Prime number (answer y or n)?"
  while read ANSWER
  do
    test "$ANSWER" == "y" && echo "Prime" && break
    test "$ANSWER" == "n" && echo "Non-prime" && break
    test "$ANSWER" != "y" -a "$ANSWER" != "n" && echo "Type y or n"
  done
done 3< 1_to_5_file.txt
```

Please note that compared to the code in the question, the last line has `3<` instead of just `3`.

Comment: It would be simpler to put `1_to_5_file.txt` on file descriptor 3 rather than copying the inherited standard input around. `while read NUMBER <&3; do ... done <3 1_to_5_file.txt`.

Comment: @chepner added improved solution based on your suggestion.